# Make changes to git forked repo and get the updated code through git URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, resque, gemfile

I have forked resque repo from Github and made some changes to tag v1.20.0. Then I want to get the changed code from Github using git URL in the Gem file.

gem 'resque', :git => "git://github.com/forked_repo/resque.git", :tag => "v1.20.0"

Actually when I made the changes a branch with the tag_name was created in the forked repo. So, I tried the below line in Gem file too.

gem 'resque', :git => "git://github.com/forked_repo/resque.git", :branch => "v1.20.0"

But, I'm not getting the new changes (into bundler) which I have changed. I'm getting the repo code for the v1.20.0 without my changes.

I have logged into the Github and edited the changes there.

Please suggest a solution here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just point it to the specific commit that has your most recent change:

```
gem 'resque', :git => "git://github.com/forked_repo/resque.git", :ref => "abcdef"
```

Just make sure you do a `bundle update resque` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks @ctide for the answer. Sorry, forgot to mention this in the question. I have tried that option too. Ran bundle update resque too... But, no luck. Still I was getting the old code in my bundler gems folder

Comment: There was some problem while creating the branch. I ignored that. I have forked again and tried the steps suggested by @ctide. It's working. Thanks.